# VMWare vSphere Distributed Switch configuration of two ESXi Host

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have two ESXi hosts (5.1 and 5.5) that I added them to a vSphere Distributed Switch. The VMs in each host can ping other VMs in the same host but cannot ping other host's VMs.

All the VMs are part of a same port group. And I want to have level 2 network connectivity between my all the VMs. 
My network topology is as the following:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does your uplink interface allow the VLANs associated with your port groups?

Comment: I do not use any VLAN in my networks(physical/virtual).